# How to align a widget to the right of a dynamic centered widget in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a text widget in the center that has a dynamic width. However, I want to add in a widget to the right of this text widget.

Because this center text wiget has a dynamic width, I cannot use absolute positioning widgets such as Align or the Position Widget. I am looking for something similar to RelativeLayout in Android.

[image]

```
  Widget body() {
    return Container(
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text('Center text'),
          FlatButton(
            child: Text('next'),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

With @Igors method I can end with a center widget with a button on each end evenly spaced. I am aiming for the button to be to the right of.

```
  Widget body() {
    return Container(
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: FlatButton(
              child: Text('next'),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
          ),
          Container(color: Colors.red, child: Text('test')),
          Expanded(
            child: FlatButton(
              child: Text('next'),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Edit: Solved through the use of Sized Box on each side of the centered widget 1.

Comment: Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```dart
Row(
  children: <Widget>[
    Expanded(
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.green
      ),
    ),
    Container(
      color: Colors.red,
      child: Text('test')
    ),
    Expanded(
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.blue
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```

Comment: Hey @igor. That's a good idea and it is very close to the solution. Please see my edited post which consist of a center text and a button to the right of it. Following your method I can get a center text but with two buttons, is there a way to hide the left button?

Comment: @Petersicecream You can use Opacity widget to visually hide it and IgnorePointer to disable any taps on it.

Comment: You can also use `Spacer()`, which technically is an `Expanded` with a SizedBox of 0 as a child, if you just need some space :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the Widget Row and add the text widget in a Container Widget.

And add margin for the Container